# Can you open a Jenkins job to a group of users without access to repo /adding to jenkins build

Tags: git, jenkins

I Built an app , on git and run it via jenkins cf ci (very new to it, someone helped set up the build).  The problem is only foks who have write access to the repo, can execute the build.
The other alternative is to give everyone access to the cfci- both of which arent possible. I would like other teams/developers to try this out..
any suggestions on how to go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

For a Jenkins job to run, you don't need to give "everyone" access to a repo.

Depending on the Git server, you can generate an access token (see for instance [Create your access token](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/blueocean/creating-pipelines/#create-your-access-token)) in order to give access to the Jenkins Job to your GitHub repository.